# Undefined variable error although the variable IS present in an already included file

Tags: php, scope, include, require

I have a PHP script named constants.php

***constants.php:-***

```
<?php
$projectRoot = "path/to/project/folder";
...
?>
```

And then I have another file named lib.php

***lib.php:-***

```
<?php
class Utils {
  function doSomething() {
    ...
    // Here we do some processing where we need the $projectRoot variable.
    $a = $projectRoot; //////HERE, I GET THE ERROR MENTIONED BELOW.
    ...
  }
}
?>
```

And then I have another file named index.php, which includes both of the above files.

***index.php:-***

```
<?php
...
require_once "constants.php";

...

require_once "lib.php";
(new Utils())->doSomething();
...
?>
```

Now, the problem is that when I run index.php, I get the following Error:

**Notice: Undefined variable: projectRootPath in /var/www/html/test/lib.php on line 19**

My question is that why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it?

Apparently, it is related to scope, but I have read the `include` and `require` simple copy and paste the included code into the script where it is included. So I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you are accessing variable in function scope.

Variables outside function are not accessible inside function.

You need to either pass them as arguments or you need to add keyword `global` to access it.

```
function doSomething() {
 global $projectRoot;
    ...
    // Here we do some processing where we need the $projectRoot variable.
    $a = $projectRoot;
```

As per `@RiggsFolly`:

**Pass as a parameter**

```
require_once "lib.php";
(new Utils())->doSomething($projectRoot);
```

...

```
<?php
class Utils {
  function doSomething($projectRoot) {
    ...
    // Here we do some processing where we need the $projectRoot variable.
    $a = $projectRoot; //////HERE, I GET THE ERROR MENTIONED BELOW.
    ...
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: OUCH! Global?? Would be better to pass the value on the function call everytime

Comment: @RiggsFolly Why is that better?

Comment: Because you are never completely sure what a global will contain at any one point in time. By vertue of it being accessible from anywhere, anything may have changed its value meaning it wont be what you expect it to be when you get into the function